# Is there an alternative to TMediaPlayer for multi platform rapid sound effects?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am looking for a way to play multiple rapid sound effects (WAV format) in a multi-platform game (Android and Windows) with low overhead.

I tried using the TMediaPlayer component, but creating multiple instances adds a lot of overhead to startup and shutdown times.

I researched and found this code which offers a low-overhead approach. Sadly, the code is incompatible with Delphi 10.2 (Tokyo) under Android (windows works fine). Under Android, the onLoadComplete is never triggered, causing the GLoaded flag to remain false and the app to freeze.
http://www.fmxexpress.com/free-game-audio-manager-wrapper-class-in-delphi-xe6-firemonkey-for-android-ios-windows-and-osx/

Does anyone know of an alternative solution or can understand why the GameAudioManager callback function fails to trigger?

Comment: It might help to provide code of how you're actually using TGameAudioManager. I'm guessing that onLoadComplete will not be called if the file does not exist, for example

Comment: The mutli-platform sample code (that includes several wav files) included in the GameAudioManager archive freezes. I  also double checked that 'fileexists' returns true.  This is the archive http://www.fmxexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/GameAudioManager.7z

Comment: Have you checked BASS audio library (https://www.un4seen.com/). Now it isn't free but it does support all of the platforms Delphi supports. Not to mention that it also supports a whole slew of different file formants. Also unlike game audio manager that you mention BASS audio is suitable for playing both short or longer audio files and you can control by yourself whether you want to play certain file from memory or directly from disk.

Comment: I'm not sure any revenue from my game will even cover the licensing cost, so right now I'm trying to find a free alternative, but in case this changes, I've bookmarked your suggestion.

Comment: For android/ios you can try ALvideoPlayer (https://github.com/Zeus64/alcinoe) and use it to play only sound. I load at startup time around 10 video player in less than 100ms

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: My initial test was done with Berlin while OP is using Tokyo. The results below hold true for Berlin. Please see further down for Tokyo.**

I was curious as to why the code in the FMXExpress link you provided did not work since I use very similar code in my multi-platform audio class. So I decided to download the code and give it a try.

The demo app looks for 3 specific files ding1.wav, ding2.wav and ding3.wav; on Windows it looks for the files in the documents folder and on Android it expects the files in assets\internal

For Windows I had to copy some audio files I had to the documents folder and rename them accordingly.  The app worked fine as you reported.  (Windows 10 Version 1709).

For Android I first took a look at the project's **deployment settings**. The 3x audio files are listed but the local path is blank. I just unchecked the existing entries and re-added them from my documents folder and set the **remote path** for each to **assets\internal**.  Compiled the app directly on a device I had connected and it worked fine.  Android SDK 24.3.3 32-bit, LG-V522 G-Pad III running Android 7.0

**EDIT - DESCRIPTION OF PROBLEM WITH TOKYO:**

The OP is correct; the linked sample code does not work when compiled with Tokyo 10.2.3

Simple debugging showed that the callback `TOnSpoolLoadCallBack.onLoadComplete` is never called which is required to set the global `GLoaded` to `True`.  The effect is that the application loops indefinitely in the following code:

**TGameAudioManager.AddSound**

```
while not GLoaded do
begin
  Sleep(10);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

To make the code work, (this is a hack) add a counter that limits the number of time the loop can run. Something like this...

```
procedure TGameAudioManager.AddSound(...)
const
  MaxWaitLoop = 10;
var
  ...
  loopCount : integer;
Begin
  ...
  loopCount := 0;
  while not GLoaded AND (loopCount < MaxWaitLoop) do
  begin
    inc(loopCount);
    Sleep(10);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
  ...
```

With some logic to prevent indefinite looping, the application now works and audio is heard on the Android device.

**Notes:**

- You now need to figure out why the callback does not work in Tokyo. After a quick check and comparison with Berlin it wasn't obvious to me.
- You should not use this code in production.
  `Application.ProcessMessages` almost always points to a bad
  implementation. Instead, the callback should bubble up to your main application where you can, for example, enable UI elements

Comment: I'm confused, the local path is blank for the 3x wav files in deployment because they are in the same path as the project file. I'm using the same version Android SDK as you. Even so, I unchecked the deployment entries, copied the audio files to 'my documents' then added them from 'my documents' and set the remote path. I tested on 2 devices (Galaxy S2, Galaxy Note4) and on the NOX emulator with no difference. Note that the original code checks "fileexists" before even trying to add the sound so that's not the issue. For me as soon as I click the "Add sounds" button, the sample app freezes.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to replicate my finding (of the freeze due to callback not being called).  The question is, if I don't have a reliable callback function that lets me know that the audio is loaded, how can I know when the audio is ready for playback?  I haven't been able to figure out why the callback isn't triggered in Tokyo.

Comment: I think its a bug in Tokyo so I created a QC report here https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-20370 . You can either use Berlin for now, wait for a response on the QC report and/or post another question specifically on the callback not firing.

Comment: I currently don't have time to look at your issue more deeply, but some hints: Tokyo changed threading model on Android. Above code as-is will no longer work. Previously callback and your blocking loop were running on separate threads, now you are blocking the thread with loop and callback simply does not have the chance. Forget about synchronous programming, remove blocking loops and use callback as it is meant to be used by adding logic that needs to run after the callback into the callback. Even if it means you need to add additional event that will run custom code,

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's a newer version of the 'GameAudioManager' unit (now dubbed "AudioManager") that is compatible with Android on Delphi Tokyo. I reviewed the code and it seems to just remove the "onload" callback and 'loaded' check-loop.

Here is the updated code:
https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiArcadeGames/blob/master/Full/AlienInvasion/AudioManager.pas